# AutoComplete ComboBox in DataGridView using C#.net Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms

Can any one tell how to implement AutoComplete for ComboBox in winforms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Suggest Append ComboBox in DataGridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075724/how-to-suggest-append-combobox-in-datagridview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you gone through this property

```
AutoCompleteCustomSource, AutoCompleteMode and AutoCompleteSource.
```

For more check this [Combo](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/aa04e6/6258/)