# How to set AutoComplete for a DataGridView Combobox Column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a DGV, connected to a DataSet which is connected to a database, with 8 columns. One of these columns is a combobox with the following settings

[image]

At the moment the autocomplete (by default) works like this: If I type in 'a' I get all entries starting with 'a'. But that's it. If I type in 'An' it does not go to e.g. Andalusia.

I already checked the combobox settings, where you can set the autocomplete mode and source and so an but then I saw, that I do not have these settings within the properties you can see above.

Does anyone know how I can get the autocomplete I would like to have accomplished?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Suggest Append ComboBox in DataGridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075724/how-to-suggest-append-combobox-in-datagridview)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can handle [`EditingControlShowing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event of `DataGridView` and using `Control` property of the event argument, get [`DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxeditingcontrol?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) which is derived from `ComboBox`.

Then you can set its [`AutoCompleteMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to available options. You also should set its [`DropDownStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown` to let the user type in control.

```
void grid_EditingControlShowing(object s, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
    if(comboBox!=null)
    {
        comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
        comboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I posted answer as C#, I'll add C# tag to the question.